# Can I change grandparent inline CSS without triggering a re-render?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to change a component's inline CSS by clicking one of its 10,000 grandchildren.

`World` passes a callback function to its child `Terrain`. This component creates a grid of 100 by 100 child components `Tile`. Each one has a position property, which can be passed to the callback, informing `World` to change its CSS so that the clicked `Tile` is moved to the center of the screen.

The following code works, but is very slow. Apparently, [`setState` always triggers a re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381736/react-setstate-flux-does-it-always-trigger-a-re-render). Because my `World` has 10,000 `Tile` grandchildren, the response of `World` moving on the screen is laggy.

I've confirmed the lag is caused by the amount of elements, because creating a `Terrain` with only 4 `Tile` children makes the click response very snappy.

**Since `setState` triggers a re-render, how else can I change `World`'s inline CSS based on which `Tile` is clicked?**

```
class World extends Component {
    // this function is passed down to Terrain
    changePosition( newPosition ) {
        this.setState({
            position : newPosition
        });
    }

    convertPosition( position ) {
        let x = ( this.tileSize / 2 ) + ( position.x * this.tileSize );
        let y = ( this.tileSize / 2 ) + ( position.y * this.tileSize );
        let translate = 'translate( ' + -x + 'px, ' + -y + 'px )';
        return translate;
    }

    render() {
        let terrainSize = {
            x : 100,
            y : 100
        };
        let style = {
            transform : this.convertPosition( this.state.position ),
            width     : terrainSize.x * this.tileSize,
            height    : terrainSize.y * this.tileSize
        };
        return (
            <div className="world" style={ style }>
                <Terrain
                    size={ terrainSize }
                    tileSize={ this.tileSize }
                    onTileClick={ this.changePosition.bind( this ) }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Terrain extends Component {
    tileClicked( position ) {
        this.props.onTileClick( position );
    }

    render() {
        let tiles = [];
        // create 100 * 100 Tiles
        for( let x = 0; x < this.props.size.x; ++x ) {
            for( let y = 0; y < this.props.size.y; ++y ) {
                let position = {
                    x : x,
                    y : y
                };
                tiles.push(
                    <Tile
                        key={ x + ',' + y }
                        position={ position }
                        size={ this.props.tileSize }
                        onClick={ () => this.tileClicked( position ) }
                    />
                );
            }
        }
        return (
            <div className="terrain">
                { tiles }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Tile extends Component {
    render() {
        let style = {
            position : 'absolute',
            top      : this.props.position.y * this.props.size,
            left     : this.props.position.x * this.props.size,
            width    : this.props.size,
            height   : this.props.size
        };
        return (
            <div className="tile" onClick={ this.props.onClick } style={ style }></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement shouldComponentUpdate() [(Optimizing Performance
 Documentation)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html) in your grandchildrens to prevent them from re-render, when they are not affected.

Comment: Applying that function to `Terrain` component seems to significantly speed up the response, indeed. Would you care to make that a full answer and explain why that works? Also, eventually, I'd need to update and re-render `Terrain`. How can I differentiate between a `Tile` click (and not re-render) and everything else?

Comment: React doesn't know (or care) which states/props your component is really depending on. You have to do this yourself by implementing the shouldComponentUpdate() method. Otherwise, you code is not optimized. 

There is also a [ESLint Plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-optimization.md) which remembers you to implement that. :)

Comment: I thought React did some smart diffing, and figured out only my `World` inline CSS changed, and all children remain the same.

Comment: @MarcDingena To do the smart diffing, it must still render the complete new tree into the virtual DOM, which in itself can be time consuming.  The `shouldComponentUpdate` function lets React skip the virtual render for the component as well as the actual render, making the whole process much faster.

Comment: Also, you can use [`React.PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) to automatically implement a `shouldComponentUpdate` function that shallow compares the props to save some effort, but you will need to be wary of the `onTileClick` prop [as the `bind` will make it never shallowly equal](https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f#9bed), so the optimisation will be lost.